# Rails no route match POST url on update with single resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, resources

I'm creating a Rails application where there is a resource used as general settings for the whole website. I set everything as follows:

**config/routes.rb**

```
authenticate :user do
  scope '/admin' do
    resource :basics #This is my resource's name, put in singular 
    # ...
  end
end
```

**controllers/basics_controller.rb**

```
private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_basic
  @basic = Basic.first
end
```

**views/basics/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @basics, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Here is what `rake routes` shows about this resource:

```
new_basics GET    /admin/basics/new(.:format)      basics#new
edit_basics GET    /admin/basics/edit(.:format)    basics#edit
basics GET    /admin/basics(.:format)              basics#show
       PATCH  /admin/basics(.:format)              basics#update
       PUT    /admin/basics(.:format)              basics#update
       DELETE /admin/basics(.:format)              basics#destroy
       POST   /admin/basics(.:format)              basics#create
```

I don't have any trouble making the form show up. However, when I submit it, I get the following error:

> No route matches [POST] "/admin/basics/edit"

When I look at the HTML generated form, I can see that it passes "/admin/basics/edit" as an action while it should be just "/admin/basics" in my situation.

What should I do to make this work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like maybe you have the wrong instance variable passed to the `form_with` method? IIRC, Rails assumes the form action should be the same as the current path if the model argument is nil.

`@basics` is not defined (at least in the controller code you shared). Replacing it with `@basic` might work for edits (when `Basic.first` exists), but not create (if `Basic.first` doesn't exist).

You could try initializing `@basic` in your controller like this

```
def set_basic
  @basic = Basic.first_or_initialize
end
```

Then pass it to `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(model: @basic, local: true) do |form| %>
```

Comment: I changed my set_basic method and changed `@basics`  to `@basic`, however, when I reload the page, I get `undefined method 'basic_path' for Method, did you mean 'basics_path'?`. If I let `@basics`, it still doesn't work.. Strange.

Comment: Seems like a resource vs resources issue. Try using `resources :basics` in your routes.rb?

Comment: If you want to use `resource :basic`, it looks like you must specify the `url: basic_path` as well: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Comment: That was it! The url was missing, now everything works, thank you!